# Is there a way to set PYTHONPATH permanently?

Tags: python, linux, pythonpath

Every day, when I open an Ubuntu terminal and want to run a python project, I have to run previously `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)`. Is there a way to avoid doing this every time I switch on my computer? Is there a way to set my `PYTHONPATH` permanently for that project?

Comment: Alternatively, you could move your local packages into ~/.local/lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following line in your ~/.bashrc file:

`export PYTHONPATH=/the/location/of/the/path`

Answer (score 4):

Have you try adding the line you mention

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)
```

to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set it permanently through the `~/.bashrc` file or `~/.profile` file for your user. Just enter the line you showed into either of those files.